# How to wrap subsection items in slide headline in beamer?

Tags: beamer, headline

My navigation bar is divided into 2 parts, which I have sections in one part and subsections in the other part. The number of sections and subsections is too much to fit in one line. I want them to be wrapped. I found the following code in a question answered some years ago, but it is written for wrapping sections. What change should I make on the code so that it works for subsections too?

Here is the code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal#1#2#3{%
 \hbox to #1{{%
   \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
   #2\hskip.3cm%
   \newdimen\tmp@parbox%
   \setlength\tmp@parbox{#1}%
   \addtolength\tmp@parbox{-.6cm}%
   \parbox{\tmp@parbox}{\raggedleft%
     \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{}%
     \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
     \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
     \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill\dohead%
     \box\beamer@sectionbox}\hfil\hskip.3cm%
     #3}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so we can see which kind of theme you use.